# Firebase Auth does not print user signed in though user is there

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have created Firebase Auth uid and email (which have been created by "Add user" as seen in image below"-

[image]

I am trying to transfer this id to Firestore with the help of code below:-

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

 class UserIdtoFirestoreViewController: UIViewController {
     let db = Firestore.firestore()
     var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
     let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    
     @IBAction func GetUserId(_ sender: UIButton) { 
         print("button pressed")
         Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in       
             if user != nil {
                 print("current user is  \(user)")
                 let email = user!.email
                 let uid = user!.uid
                 let db = Firestore.firestore()
         
                 db.collection("users")
                   .document(uid)
                   .setData([
                     "email":email,"uid":uid
                   ])

        } else { 
            print("no user is signed in")}
        }
    }
}
```

But it prints -

button pressed

no user is signed in

Also,  the Firestore Database is empty as you can see:-

[image]

How to transfer Auth data from Authentication to Firestore?

Comment: With your code you're only adding an event listener, but you're never calling the authentication mechanism. Are you calling it elsewhere? (to be clear: I don't see any code that's sending username and password to firebase auth). Also, you're adding a listener everytime a button is pressed, and that's not a good thing, because it will lead to executing the same listener multiple times each time the button is pressed again

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should sign in existing user and then you will see users information in authentication state listener.
This is example of singing user with email/password authentication

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] authResult, error in  
  guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
  // ...
}
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#sign_in_existing_users